# Identifying all rows with the same record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the below.

I want to be able to identify all the different `Custodians` that have the same `MD5hash`.

The result should be the `ArtifactID` and the `Custodian` ID as a new row. For example:

```
1098647, 1098624
1098648, 1098717
1098648, 1098624
1098647, 1098717
```

The table looks like this:

```
ArtifactID      md5Hash                             Custodian
1098647         e6ae2fbc906c42b55d25f6d660f4913a    1098624
1098648         e6ae2fbc906c42b55d25f6d660f4913a    1098717
1098649         9f0c88c40be3d01b6beed39b32dea3fb    1098624
1098650         39446d6f0a5b29fef001c184797349b4    1098624
1098651         35ec5012284256c97553b5342fd59530    1098624
1098652         0914cd30b41460efaab7d6703444a5de    1098624
1098653         929eefb170bc74ed3cfabae969a032ed    1098624
1098654         d8986a76130fde673bbf5f1f9fb82857    1098624
1098655         6399df1a2ca3fde7021da25e4aa9e722    1098624
1098656         a19701c034af4094bc3da149d1e9b8d1    1098624
1098657         8384d8e0562391ee02c731fc059b510c    1098624
1098658         94800202b4473f8ce3dc08ddea4aff0c    1098624
1098659         87388b9895c749147d5a19a8ccd9c865    1098624
```

Comment: Why are you retrieving Artifact 1098648 with custodian 1098624 in your desired result?

Comment: For each MD5Hash, I need to identify the custodians owners of each. In the above example, Artifact ID 1098647 is owned by Custodian 1098624 and 1098717. Artifact ID 1098648 is owned by Custodian 1098624 and 1098717. Therefore, there should be 4 rows returned with each permutation of owner.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your table's content. I don't see artifact 1098647 linked to custodian 1098717, the only link would be through the md5Hash, but that would indicate that a custodian is linked to a md5Hash and not to the artifact itself. You data in that case should be split in 2 tables, one with Artifact + Hash and another with Hash + Custodian.

Comment: Sorry, the link is with MD5hash. Should have explained that a bit better. I am unable to split the data into two tables, the system is not one that can be changed in such a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine which hashes are repeated with different custodians, then retrieve those custodians.

**EDIT**: It seems that your desired outcome involves an implicit relationship stored in your table. I try to differentiate this relationship in the following CTEs. This should get what you need.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ArtifactID INT,
    md5Hash VARCHAR(200),
    Custodian INT)

INSERT INTO #Data (
    ArtifactID,
    md5Hash,
    Custodian)
VALUES
    (1098647, 'e6ae2fbc906c42b55d25f6d660f4913a', 1098624), 
    (1098648, 'e6ae2fbc906c42b55d25f6d660f4913a', 1098717), 
    (1098649, '9f0c88c40be3d01b6beed39b32dea3fb', 1098624), 
    (1098650, '39446d6f0a5b29fef001c184797349b4', 1098624), 
    (1098651, '35ec5012284256c97553b5342fd59530', 1098624), 
    (1098652, '0914cd30b41460efaab7d6703444a5de', 1098624), 
    (1098653, '929eefb170bc74ed3cfabae969a032ed', 1098624), 
    (1098654, 'd8986a76130fde673bbf5f1f9fb82857', 1098624), 
    (1098655, '6399df1a2ca3fde7021da25e4aa9e722', 1098624), 
    (1098656, 'a19701c034af4094bc3da149d1e9b8d1', 1098624), 
    (1098657, '8384d8e0562391ee02c731fc059b510c', 1098624), 
    (1098658, '94800202b4473f8ce3dc08ddea4aff0c', 1098624), 
    (1098659, '87388b9895c749147d5a19a8ccd9c865', 1098624)

;WITH Artifacts AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        D.ArtifactID,
        D.md5Hash
    FROM
        #Data AS D
),
Custodians AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        D.Custodian,
        D.md5Hash
    FROM
        #Data AS D
),
RepeatedHash AS
(
    SELECT
        T.md5Hash
    FROM
        Custodians AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.md5Hash
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT(T.Custodian)) > 1
)
SELECT
    A.ArtifactID,
    C.Custodian
FROM
    RepeatedHash AS R
    INNER JOIN Custodians AS C ON R.md5Hash = C.md5Hash
    INNER JOIN Artifacts AS A ON R.md5Hash = A.md5Hash
```

Comment: Perfect, accepting this answer as I love CTE's! Thanks

Comment: Just changed my original question slightly

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the table on the `md5Hash` field. The subquery will group the record by the `md5Hash` field and only return the ones with repetition:

```
SELECT ArtifactID, Custodian
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (SELECT md5Hash
            FROM table1
            GROUP BY md5Hash
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
           ) tt ON t.md5Hash = tt.md5Hash
```

**EDIT** Your update indicates that your table is not properly normalized. It's strongly recommended to normalize your table. To get the desired results with the current table design, you need to subqueries like the one above, one for `ArtifactID` with `md5Hash` and another for `Custodian` with `md5Hash`, then you can join the two on the implicit relationship `md5Hash`:

```
SELECT ArtifactID, Custodian
FROM(SELECT ArtifactID, t.md5Hash
     FROM table1 t
     INNER JOIN (SELECT md5Hash
                 FROM table1
                 GROUP BY md5Hash
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                ) tt ON t.md5Hash = tt.md5Hash
    ) q1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Custodian, t.md5Hash
            FROM table1 t
            INNER JOIN (SELECT md5Hash
                        FROM table1
                        GROUP BY md5Hash
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                       ) tt ON t.md5Hash = tt.md5Hash
) q2 ON q1.md5Hash = q2.md5Hash
```